# Azure redirecting app service to custom domain

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I am trying to redirect the default domain to a custom domain using web.config file in root directory of app service.
In my case, https://default.azurewebsites.net to https://app.customdomain.com which is working but https://default.azurewebsites.net/login is not redirecting to https://app.customdomain.com
my working config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
       </rule>
          <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^default\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://app.customdomain.com/{R:0}"  />  
          </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also tried adding two rules it didn't work

```
    <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain for login" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)/login" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^default\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://app.customdomain.com/login/{R:0}"  />  
          </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^default\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://app.customdomain.com/{R:0}"  />  
          </rule>
```

Also tried one rule with multiple conditions. didn't work

```
<rule name="Redirect rquests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^default\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^default\.azurewebsites\.net/login" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://https://app.customdomain.com/{R:0}"  />  
          </rule>
```

few more combinations with regex also tried but still no luck.

Comment: Are you redirecting to another website ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: @Thomas
I have an app service where an angular  website hosted which has 
default domain as default.azurewebsites.net
I also configured a custom domain for that same app service as app.customdomain.com

If I acess the below URL 
default.azurewebsites.net redirects to app.customdomain.com -> OK
default.azurewebsites.net/login redirects to default.azurewebsites.net/login -> KO

Expected output 
default.azurewebsites.net/login -> app.customdomain.com

similar to https://www.zainrizvi.io/blog/block-default-azure-websites-domain/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect default azure domain to custom domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testing\.azurewebsites\.net" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://grew.mydomain.com/login"  />
                </rule>
                
                <rule name="Redirect default azure domain login url to custom domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)^login" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testing\.azurewebsites\.net" />
                        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/login" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://grew.mydomain.com/login"  />
                </rule>
                
                <rule name="Angular rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Finally the above web.config file worked!!!
Redirecting rule should be defined above the angular rule and rule name should be unique

Answer (score 0):

## Use `<match url="(.*)^login" />`, it works for me.

**Please check my test result first.**

[image]

[image]

My `web.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="a page" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)^a" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://jasonp2.azurewebsites.net/a.html" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="b page" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)^b" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://jasonp2.azurewebsites.net/b.html" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.. let me test and update you here

Comment: Tried..but still no luck

Comment: You were right.. but the misplacement of angular rule caused the error..Thanks anyway